# How to randomly generate a matrix with n 0s and m 1s in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, random

For example, how to randomly generate a 1-by-12 matrix that contains 8 `0`s and 4 `1`s?

Like this matrix `[1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0]`

And if I generate again, it returns a different matrix `[0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0]`

Comment: Do you mean 4 0s and 8 1s or 8 0s and 4 1s? Because you say the former but give examples of the latter.

Comment: Sorry i made this stupid mistake...I doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a vector that starts with the desired number of `1`s followed by the desired number of `0`s and the use [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) to shuffle it around:

```
n = 8;
m = 4;
M = [ones(m,1), zeros(n,1)];
M = M(randperm(numel(M)))
```

Or you can do it slightly differently: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/83289-how-can-i-create-a-random-binary-matrix-with-a-specified-number-of-1-s-and-0-s

Answer (score 4):

You can make a vector containing 12 zeros and use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) to pick four numbers that you make one:

```
a = zeros(1,12);
a(randsample(12,4)) = 1;
```

Note: This requires the '[Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/pl_trial_R2014b_ST)'.
If you do not have this, you will not be able to use `randsample`.

Answer (score 1):

This one may work as well.

```
x = zeros(12,1);
tmp = rand(12,1);
[~,ind] = sort(tmp);
x(ind(1:4)) = 1;
```

Not sure if is better than the other examples, but it is **one** way to do it. I would say it is a similar solution as the one by [fhdrsdg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30350593/2903371), but this one does not requires statistics toolbox. It mat also be possible that this solution may not have the same elegance as matlabs solutions may have though and `randsample` have more features than this example.